# Unable to add Dependencies in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I've been trying to add Maven dependencies to use in my Java project using the Eclipse built-in manager, and something isn't working. I can add to the Dependency Management side on the right, but whenever I fill out the artifact id and such and hit OK under the Dependencies side on the left, nothing happens.

It also should be noted that the search feature isn't working, and whenever I type something in, the progress console spits out "Repository search (sleeping)". I've tried rebuilding the Global Repository index (which sits at 0% for 5 minutes and then stops), enabling the entire index, and checking the "Download repository index updates on startup" under Window>Preferences, and none of them seem to fix the problem.

Comment: Get a better IDE - IntelliJ works beautifully with Maven.

Comment: Edit the pom.xml yourself

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "nothing happens"?  Did the GAV entry go into the list when you clicked ok?  Don't bother entering dependencies into the "dependency management" section.  That's for other poms that specify this pom as a parent.